# Unable to mount 8TB external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs, linux-mint

I plugged in an external hard drive into my computer running Linux Mint 17.2. This NTFS formatted drive has worked before, but now I get the following:

> Error mounting /dev/sdf2 at *[DIRECTORY]*: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdf2" "*[DIRECTORY]*"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdf2 is already mounted on *[DIRECTORY]*

The thing is, *[DIRECTORY]* doesn't exist and I can't unmount it. Running `df` doesn't show `/dev/sdf2`. How can I get this drive to mount?

Answer (score 0):

Review your mtab file. Delete the entry for the drive and reboot your system. Then re-mount the drive. The mtab file may be found at: /etc/mtab.